# .htaccess redirect in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I would like users that go to the website 'http://kevingstongramado.p.ht/',

to be redirected to 'http://kevingstongramado.p.ht/catalogo/'. Which is in fact a wordpress website.

I´ve tried this:

Redirect 301 /http://kevingstongramado.p.ht/ http://kevingstongramado.p.ht/catalogo/

Putting the .htaccess inside the root directory of the website. Not the root directory of the folder which contains the wordpress.

Doesn´t work.

"catalogo" is the folder which contains the 'index.php' that opens the wordpress website.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RedirectMatch

If I am not wrong, you should use the relative path.

Create the index file index.htm in your root folder. Then,

```
RedirectMatch 301 /index.htm /catalogo//$1
```

Comment: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@kevingstongramado.p.ht and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Server Apache version: Apache/2.2.14

Comment: I´ve tried your code before, and it made lots of redirections, now, don´t know why, I can´t access the website.

Try to access http://kevingstongramado.p.ht/catalogo/

Comment: The code above redirects to:

http://kevingstongramado.p.ht/catalogo//catalogo//catalogo//catalogo//catalogo//catalogo//catalogo//catalogo//catalogo//catalogo//catalogo//catalogo//catalogo//catalogo//catalogo//catalogo//catalogo//catalogo//catalogo//catalogo//catalogo//

Comment: Please, what should I do now?

Comment: Try to use a index file in your root dirctory and redirect from there:
Create the index file index.htm in your root folder. Then,

RedirectMatch 301 /index.htm /catalogo//$1

Comment: It seems to redirect ok, but I can´t access the website:

Please, check it: http://kevingstongramado.p.ht/

Comment: See the answer above. It's better to use mode_rewrite rule for this. But, you can resolve the problem currently occuring by renaming the index.htm to some other name, such as redirect.htm. And,

`RedirectMatch 301 /redirect.htm /catalogo//$1`

May be clear your browser cache, or use some other browser and try again..

Answer (score 1):

`.htaccess` files are calculated by searching and interpreting the configuration for every `.htaccess` file in every directory in the path under the document root.

You want something along the lines of

```
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !^/catalogo/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /catalogo/$1 [L]
```

This makes the rule conditional.  It will only execute the rule if `/catalogo/` is not present in the request uri.  And the actual rule says to take everything and put `/catalogo/` in front of it... and that it is the last rule to be executed in the file.  This file will be reprocessed when it goes to the `/catalogo/` directory.

Comment: Cool..Better to use mod_rewrite, yes :)

Comment: That won´t make my browser stuck?

Comment: your browser got 'stuck' because, it was storing the last response from the server ( looping redirects ). If you clear the cache, it will be fine.. It will never occur again now.

The advantage with mod_rewrite is that,

You can specify rules which does not result in infinite looping. You can shorten the URLs, and so on..

Comment: With current implementation, yes.. If you remove it, it will again result in infinite loops

Comment: Hi @Steve Buzonas.

I´ve tried your implementation. It´s not redirecting. I´ve deleted cache and cookies. And also, I´ve tried to get the other implementation back of Hariprasad, and now, doesn´t work either.

Comment: You need to enable mod_rewrite for that:

`RewriteEngine On`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30095/discussion-between-marcelo-noronha-and-hariprasad)