# PHP redirect when URL is not requested through ajax (when on a wordpress page)

Tags: php, html, ajax, apache, .htaccess

I have a Wordpress website with Domain: `Hello.com` which is "ajaxified".
what I want to know is how to redirect user back to `Hello.com` if they visit `Hello.com/ask`,  `Hello.com/cake` or anything deeper using the browser address bar.

Even if they go 2 degrees deeper like `Hello.com/cake/make`, I want them to stay at the root of my website.

I am using Wordpress and my first Idea was to put redirect script at header, but ended up making an infinite redirect loop.

How can I redirect users to homepage without redirecting my ajax requests to the homepage as well?

> [If you ask why I would disallow them to go deeper, the answer is: **I
>   am using ajax to load deeper pages and everything else into a div**]

Comment: Look into htacess http://stackoverflow.com/tags/.htaccess/info

Comment: It might be admin interfaces or another type of web application which isn't supposed to be searchable by SE.

Comment: @Stefan that's what robots.txt is for.

Comment: @raam86 Yes, that works too, but it's not quite what I was looking for since wordpress works differently, if I use htaccess, I migh not even be able to access the backend.

I'd like to do this the wordpress-friendly way :)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I was responding to a now deleted comment which said that the OP is building a SE unfriendly site.

Comment: @user2128576 htaccess also has exclude rules.

Comment: @Stefan Yes I am aware, thanks. I will add robots.txt for it, but the question is how do I redirect?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess redirect in wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596775/htaccess-redirect-in-wordpress)

Comment: @raam86 You're probably right. Thought of it after reading your comment. True, htaccess would be a good choice for doing it, but I remember having static pages that aren't part of wordpress which I would allow users to go to, and some pdf files viewable on browser. >__> The hell, it's getting really complex. I'd have to list it all, isn't there any other way to do this dynamically and apply it to wordpress pages only?

Comment: As far as I know, the least effort is to use rewrite rules in htaccess.  Otherwise you could put a redirect into each index.xyz page, using one of various ways: meta refresh, javascript window.location, php Header('Location: ') etc. Then rename the pages you load via ajax so that they aren't named index.xyz

Comment: I think, if you have are using Apache and have access to httpd.conf, you can also specify redirects there.

Comment: The question has been modified to be more helpful to site visitors. Some comments may no longer make sense, and I am sorry for the ambiguity in my question. (I was new and unprofessional back then.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By adding a short PHP script somewhere before everything else, I was able to check how my pages were loaded using the condition below.

```
if(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest')
```

It allowed me to check through PHP if it was through Ajax or not.

The value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']` is `xmlhttprequest` when the request was an ajax request.

For my case, this is how I used it:

```
if(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
    header("Location: http://". $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/");
}
```

*Which would check if the request was done through ajax, and redirect to the homepage/Main Screen of the website/web App if not.*

*I got the idea after reading [this post](http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ajax)*

---

**Note:** *Usage of HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH depends on the JavaScript framework you are using, if it sets that header. I am using jQuery and it does it for you.
Also $_SERVER is not entirely a part of PHP so it also depends if your server passes that variable to PHP.
If you are on a Nginx Server and it doesn't work for you, you can try this:
[Passing HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH from nginx to php](https://gist.github.com/toddmcbrearty/10414524)*

Hope this helps others!